# Update a textview even while user is not using my app

Tags: android, timer, textview

I basically want to create a timer. I have a textview where I need to show a timer like "Updating your location in 2min 29 secs" and I want the timer to decrement For eg 2min 28secs followed by 2min 27 secs.

And I want to update it even when the user is not using my app (I don't want it to update in real sense what I mean is when user opens my app after say 1 min then the timer should show 1min 27 secs).

Can some one please help me out in pointing out the correct and efficient way of doing this ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way in my opinion is using [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) when your activity is in foreground and when it is going to background you do not need any services you can just save the current time and the remaining time in a sharedpreferances and when again your activity comes to foreground read those values plus current time and then update the `textview` in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a service and send intents that your activity receives (the one with the TextView) using **LocalBroadcastManager**. You should register a *BroadcastReceiver* inside *Activity.onResume()*, and unregister it inside *onPause()*.

Using a **TimerTask** should be the default approach but you must be aware that if your activity is sent to background it can be killed by the system. That's why I recommend using a service.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey thanks for the ans. I do have one question though. Is it okay to broadcast intents every sec? since I want my textview to update by sec not by min.

Comment: You could toggle a flag in the application object that indicates if activity is *resumed* or *paused*. Checking that will allow you to broadcast from your service only when the activity is in foreground.